# I want initialize two variables to a 2d Array in C language

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, multidimensional-array

I am trying to initialize a 2D array to two variable values but it's giving me an error, Maybe I am not initializing it right line number 15 is where I am getting the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, puts, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */

int main ()
{
  int r, i,j,l[i][j],M = 18, Ma = 30, array[7][2];
  srand (time(NULL));

  for(i=0; i < 7 ; i++)
  {     
  for (int j=0; j<2;j++)
  { int x=Ma + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (M - Ma + 1) + 1);
    int y=rand() % 10 + 1;
    l[i][j]={x,y};
    array[i][j] = l[i][j];
    printf("%d\t",array[i][j]);
  }
  printf("\n");    

  }
  printf("\n") ;
  return 0;;
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: in `int r, i,j,l[i][j],M = 18, Ma = 30, array[7][2];`, `l[i][j]` is death. `i` and `j` have no values yet, so the size of this array will be undefined.

Comment: /Users/deviprasadtripathy/Documents/test/hw2/main.c:15:17: error: expected expression
        l[i][j]={x,y};
                ^
1 error generated.

Comment: You can't initialize VLAs and you can't do array assignment either.

Comment: `array[i][j]` addresses *exactly  one* integer. What makes you assume, you could store *two* values (`x` and `y`) in there?

Answer (score -1):

in initialization you can't write variables so in place of l[i][j] mention l[10][10] then error will not occur.